# Xamarin unable to connect to mysql

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, xamarin, xamarin.android

`db` is my MySqlConnection. When I'm trying to run: `db.Open();` I get this error:

> The type 'System.Data.Common.DbConnection' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089”.

So I followed it and added `System.Data` reference. Now I get this error:

> Reference to type 'Component' claims it is defined in System but it could not be found

I am using .NET Framework v4.0, MySQL Connector v6.9.9, Xamarin Forms v2.3.2.127 and all Android Support v23.4.0.1

P.S. I read something about PCL but I don't know if the package I am using i PCL.

Comment: share the connection string.

Comment: ` db = new MySqlConnection("Server=192.168.56.2;port=3306;User Id=user;Password=aa");`

Answer (score 0):

Please specify database name in connection string

```
Server=myServerAddress;Port=1234;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;
Pwd=myPassword
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's not a great solution, but I moved entire code to specific Android project and it works perfectly.